# Getting incorrect datas when I am trying to retrieve them from SQL database

Tags: android

I am trying to make an dialer app where I want to display all the contacts(Name and phone number) in a listview. The problem is whenever I am displaying the values on the listview, its showing incorrect phone number for the person. For example, If person A has phone number 123 and person B has phone number 456, then its showing phone number 456 for person A and phone number 123 for person B.
Below are my java classes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout rl1;
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0,bhash,bStar,del,call;
    EditText editText;
    Intent phoneIntent,callIntent;
    ListView lv;
    int c=0;
     List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    DBHelper dbhelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
       // dbhelper.onCreate();
        rl1=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        rl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        b9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
        b0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
        bhash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHash);
        bStar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStar);
        call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
        del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDel);


        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String NamePhone = name1.get(position);
                String tempName = temp.get(position);
                String tempPhone = NamePhone.replace(tempName,"");
                String phone = tempPhone.trim();
                editText.setText(phone);
            }
        });

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               // Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                rl1.setVisibility(rl1.isShown()?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
                c++;
                if (c%2==0)
                {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer));
                }
                else {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.collaspe));
                }
                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"1" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"2"+str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);

                    }
                });
                b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"3" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"4" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"5" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"6" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"7" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"8" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"9" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"0" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                bhash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"#" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                bStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"*" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String number = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (number.charAt(0)!='*') {
                            if (number.length()<=9)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                                startActivity(phoneIntent);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (number.subSequence(number.length()-1,number.length()).equals("#"))
                        {
                            number = number.substring(0, number.length() - 1);
                            String callInfo = "tel:" + number + Uri.encode("#");
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(callInfo));
                            startActivity(callIntent);
                        }
                    }
                });
                del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int posElse =  editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String text = editText.getText().toString();
                        if(text.length()!=0 && posElse >= 1) {
                            int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                            String str1 = (String) text.substring(0, pos-1);
                            if(str1.equals(null))
                            {

                            }
                            String str2 = (String) text.substring(pos);
                            String latest = str1+str2;
                            editText.setText(latest);
                            int pos1 = pos-1;
                            editText.setSelection(pos1);
                        }
                        else if ( posElse < 1)
                        {
                            int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();

                            String str2 = (String) text.substring(pos);
                            String latest = str2;
                            editText.setText(latest);
                            int pos1 = pos;
                            editText.setSelection(pos1);
                        }
                    }
                });

                del.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        if (del.equals(v))
                        {
                            editText.setText("");
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //Get the Contacts
    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
       // Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
           // String NameAndPhone = name +"\n"+ phoneNumber;
            //name1.add(NameAndPhone);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
            //temp.add(name);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            //Collections.sort(name1);
           // Collections.sort(temp);

            String name2 = name1.get(position);
           String phone2 = phno1.get(position);

            dbhelper.save(name2,phone2);

            List<String> cName = dbhelper.getName();
            List<String> cPh   = dbhelper.getPhn();

                tv.setText(cName.get(position));
              tv1.setText(cPh.get(position));

            /*String tempname = temp.get(position);
            String name2Trimmed = name2.trim();
            String tempTrimmed = tempname.trim();
            SpannableString res = new SpannableString(name2Trimmed);
            res.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, tempTrimmed.length(), 0);

            tv.setText(res);*/

            return vi;
        }

    }
}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DATABASE = "contactsdb";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE contactsdb(name VARCHAR,contacts VARCHAR);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

    public void save(String name,String phn)
    {
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO contactsdb"+ " VALUES('"+name+"','"+phn+"');");
    }

    public List<String> getName()
    {
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contactsdb",null);
        List<String> nameResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> contactsResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int phoIndex = c.getColumnIndex("contacts");
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            nameResults.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
           // contactsResults.add(c.getString(phoIndex));
        }
        return nameResults;
    }

    public List<String> getPhn()
    {
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contactsdb",null);
        List<String> nameResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> contactsResults = new ArrayList<String>();
       // int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int phoIndex = c.getColumnIndex("contacts");
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            //nameResults.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
            contactsResults.add(c.getString(phoIndex));
        }
        return contactsResults;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue of ArrayList data Order , because you are using two different arrayList for storing name and phone number. You should Make a model class like below:

```
public class Contact{

 public String name;
 public String phone;

}
```

Then createArray List for this:

```
List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Modify You method:

```
   public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
           // Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

     if(phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0)
     {
            phones.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.name = name;
                c.phone = phoneNumber;
                contactList.add(c);

            }while (phones.moveToNext());
         }

      if(phones != null){
            phones.close();
        }
 }
```

Use contactList in Your adapter class and set value int getview.

Hope It help You !

Answer (score 1):

I think error is in while loop in `getAllContacts()` function

Replace your while loop by this :-

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

if(people.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String name   = people.getString(indexName);
        String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
        // Do work...
    } while (people.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: It seems that your answer needs proper formatting. Please edit and properly format it.